# Validation error when try to update table with uuid foreign key, django 4.2

Tags: django

This may be easy, but I have not been able to solve the issue
I have 2 models wwith oneToMany relation. I am try to update the child table using foreign key of parent table, but it is returning this error:

ValidationError at /StudentParentsAssign/01b93b30-e5fb-49f8-9394-94a824b7a099/
['“c0ea3f3e-bb79-4fc5-9fd9-6bce341324d1,” is not a valid UUID.']

[image]

[image]

Below is my code:

Models.py

```
#Modeles.py
class Student(models.Model):
    #std_matricule = models.CharField(verbose_name='Student matricule', max_length=6, null=False, unique=True, primary_key=True)
    std_matricule = models.CharField(verbose_name='Matricule', unique=True, max_length=16, null=False, blank=False, help_text='Matricule of the student')
    std_parents = models.ForeignKey(Parents, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING, related_name='Parents', unique=False, null=True, blank=True, verbose_name='Student parents')
    

class Parents(models.Model):
    father_surname = models.CharField(verbose_name='Father surname', max_length=128, null=False, blank=True, help_text='Student Father surname as in the birth certificate')
    father_firstName = models.CharField(verbose_name='Father name', max_length=128, null=False, blank=True)
    parent_id = models.UUIDField(default=uuid.uuid4, unique=True, primary_key=True, editable=False)
    ....
```

view.py

```
#view.py
def StudentParentsAssign(request, pk):
    # parents_list = Parents.objects.all().order_by('father_surname')
    std = Student.objects.get(student_id = pk)
    if std.std_parents not in (None, ''):
        #  parentsList = Parents.objects.all().order_by('father_surname')
         context = {'studentObj': std}
         return render(request, "students_management_app/student_template/student-single.html", context)
    else:
        if request.method == "POST":
            perents_id = request.POST.get('radio')
            Student.objects.filter(pk=pk).update(std_parents=perents_id)
        parentList = Parents.objects.filter(parents_deleteStatus=False).order_by('-parent_createDate')
        context = {'parentList': parentList}
    return render(request, "students_management_app/student_template/student-parents-list.html", context)
```

url.py

```
#url.py 
path('studentDetails/<uuid:pk>/', views.studentDetails, name = 'student-details'),
path('StudentParentsAssign/<uuid:pk>/', views.StudentParentsAssign, name = 'student-parents-list'),
```

Template

```
#Template
{% block content %}   
    <h1>List of all parents</h1>
    {% if parentList %}
    <form action="", method="POST">
        {% csrf_token %}
    <button type="submit">Assign the selected parents</button>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <th>Select</th>
            <th>Father's full name</th>
            <th>Father's phone</th>
            <th>Mother's full name </th>
            <th>Mother's phone</th>
            <th>View</th>
            <th>Update</th>
        </tr>
        {% for parent in parentList %}
        <tr>
            <td>
                <input type="radio", value={{parent.parent_id}}, name="radio"/>
            </td>
            <td>{{parent.father_surname}} {{parent.father_firstName}}</td>
            <td>{{parent.father_phone}}</td>
            <td>{{parent.mother_firstName}} {{parent.mother_surname}} </td>
            <td>{{parent.mother_phone}}</td>
            <td><a href="{% url 'parents-details' parent.parent_id %}"> View</a></td>
            <td><a href="{% url 'parents-update' parent.parent_id %}"> Update </a></td>
            <td><a href="#"> Update </a></td>
            <td><a href="#"> Delete </a></td>
        </tr>
        {% endfor %}
    </table>
</form>
    {% else %}
    <p>No parent found in the database</p>
    {%endif%}
{% endblock content %}
```

Thank you

Comment: Could you please share the full traceback ?

Comment: I just add the traceback, inserted it as an image.
Thank you Alombaros

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how UUID FK works but I guess something like that should_work

```py
perents_id = request.POST.get('radio')
parent = Parents.objects.get(parent_id=perents_id)
Student.objects.filter(pk=pk).update(std_parents=parent)
```

Usually you'll be able to update with:

```py
perents_id = request.POST.get('radio')
Student.objects.filter(pk=pk).update(std_parents_id=perents_id)
```

But I don't know if this applies to UUID FK

Note 1: Model name should not be plurialized [tip](https://www.django-antipatterns.com/antipattern/plural-model-class-names.html)
Note 2: using `.update()` to update a single object might be detrimental because it bypasses the `.save()` [doc](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/models/querysets/#update)

Comment: Thanks @Alomboros,
I just modified it as per your suggestions, but it is not working.
I even try this and I am having the same error.

`
parents_id = request.POST.get('radio')
            parent = Parents.objects.get(parent_id=parents_id)
            # Student.objects.filter(pk=pk).update(std_parents=parent)
            std = Student.objects.filter(pk=pk)
            std = std.std_parents=parent
            std.save()
`
My application requirement is to use uuid for PK.
Thank you

Comment: I just spotted it in you question, I don't “c0ea3f3e-bb79-4fc5-9fd9-6bce341324d1,” should end with a comma.

Comment: I tried to remove the comma at the end of the uuid, but seems not working. I even tried to convert the string to uuid.  I add this

`code`
parent.replace(',', '')
            par = uuid.UUID(parent).hex
            Student.objects.filter(pk=pk).update(std_parents=par)
`code`

Answer (score 0):

I just found that an additional character was added at the end of the uuid depending on the method I used.
I used replace() function to remove and this is the view.py

```
def StudentParentsAssign(request, pk):
std = Student.objects.get(student_id = pk)
if std.std_parents not in (None, ''):
     context = {'studentObj': std}
     return render(request, "students_management_app/student_template/student-single.html", context)
else:
    if request.method == "POST":
        par_id = request.POST.get('radio') #['radio']
        par = par_id.replace('/', '')
        parent = Parents.objects.get(parent_id=par)
        Student.objects.filter(pk=pk).update(std_parents=parent)
        context = {'studentObj': std}
        return render(request, "students_management_app/student_template/student-single.html", context)
    parentList = Parents.objects.filter(parents_deleteStatus=False).order_by('-parent_createDate')
    context = {'parentList': parentList}
return render(request, "students_management_app/student_template/student-parents-list.html", context)
```

Thank @Alombaros